# Dataset API for web analytics

Tags: php, twitter, google-analytics, web-analytics, openwebanalytics

In the data mining view I know from that there is the Twitter API from which you can implement a crawler and collect data.

For web analytics purposes are there any kind of APIs?

Thank you in advance for any information.

Answer (score 0):

All the analytics tools provide an API to accompany themselves, and they tend to produce documentation that introduces all the method and variables available.

Furthermore, most widely-used web applications expose APIs of some sort. There is often data available in those interactions.

For web analytics, there's Adobe, WebTrends and Google, among others.